# systemd corruption on Ubuntu server 22.04.2

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, ubuntu-22.04

I've just upgraded my Ubuntu server **20.04 LTS** to **22.04.2 LTS** (apt update, apt upgrade, apt dist-upgrade, do-release-upgrade, apt full-upgrade) and after the upgrade ended up with `systemd corruption` which is preventing the system to run in regular conditions.

I mean, don't know why but old systemd files exists in the system and some libraries or binaries are still linked o them.

BTW, **Ubuntu 22.04.2** should use**systemd 249** but I see the following:

```
ldd /usr/bin/journalctl
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff45734000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd1d9761000)
        libsystemd-shared-245.so => not found
        libpcre2-8.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007fd1d96ca000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd1d99b3000)
```

systemd-245 libraries:

```
ldd /usr/bin/systemd-machine-id-setup
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffedc140000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd2110ea000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd21132f000)
        libsystemd-shared-245.so => not found

ldd /lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-249.so
            linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe7bd88000)
            libacl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f83140d5000)
            libblkid.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f831409e000)
            libcap.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2 (0x00007f8314093000)
            libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f8314059000)
            libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f8313f13000)
            libip4tc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libip4tc.so.2 (0x00007f8313f09000)
            libkmod.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmod.so.2 (0x00007f8313eeb000)
            liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f8313ecb000)
            libmount.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f8313e87000)
            libcrypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x00007f8313a44000)
            libpam.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0 (0x00007f8313a32000)
            libseccomp.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libseccomp.so.2 (0x00007f8313a12000)
            libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f83139e4000)
            libzstd.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007f8313915000)
            liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f83138ea000)
            libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f83136c2000)
            /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f83143ac000)
            libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f831369c000)
            libaudit.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1 (0x00007f831366c000)
            libpcre2-8.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f83135d5000)
            libcap-ng.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap-ng.so.0 (0x00007f83135cd000)
```

Errors shown during some package installation:

```
Setting up opendkim (2.11.0~beta2-6) ...
systemd-tmpfiles: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-245.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Setting up opendmarc (1.4.2-1) ...
Determining localhost credentials from /etc/mysql/debian.cnf: succeeded.
dbconfig-common: writing config to /etc/dbconfig-common/opendmarc.conf
dbconfig-common: flushing administrative password
systemd-tmpfiles: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-245.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Errors shown restarting some services:

```
Restarting php5.6-fpm (via systemctl): php5.6-fpm.serviceJob for php5.6-fpm.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status php5.6-fpm.service" and "journalctl -xeu php5.6-fpm.service" for details.
 failed!
root@we:~# journalctl -xeu php5.6-fpm.service
journalctl: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-245.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Restarting courier:

```
Restarting courier-authdaemon (via systemctl): courier-authdaemon.serviceJob for courier-authdaemon.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status courier-authdaemon.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
Restarting courier-imap (via systemctl): courier-imap.serviceA dependency job for courier-imap.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
 failed!
Restarting courier-imap-ssl (via systemctl): courier-imap-ssl.serviceA dependency job for courier-imap-ssl.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
```

`jorunalctl -xe`:

```
journalctl -xe
journalctl: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-245.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/systemd/:/usr/lib:/lib apt-get --reinstall install courier-authdaemon courier-authlib courier-authlib-mysql courier-authlib-userdb courier-base courier-imap  courier-pop libcourier-unicode`

```
Preparing to unpack .../0-courier-base_1.0.16-3build3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking courier-base (1.0.16-3build3) over (1.0.16-3build3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../1-courier-authdaemon_0.71.1-2build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking courier-authdaemon (0.71.1-2build1) over (0.71.1-2build1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../2-courier-authlib_0.71.1-2build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking courier-authlib (0.71.1-2build1) over (0.71.1-2build1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../3-courier-authlib-mysql_0.71.1-2build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking courier-authlib-mysql (0.71.1-2build1) over (0.71.1-2build1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../4-courier-authlib-userdb_0.71.1-2build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking courier-authlib-userdb (0.71.1-2build1) over (0.71.1-2build1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../5-libcourier-unicode4_2.1.2-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcourier-unicode4:amd64 (2.1.2-2) over (2.1.2-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../6-courier-imap_5.0.13+1.0.16-3build3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking courier-imap (5.0.13+1.0.16-3build3) over (5.0.13+1.0.16-3build3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../7-courier-pop_1.0.16-3build3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking courier-pop (1.0.16-3build3) over (1.0.16-3build3) ...
Setting up courier-authlib (0.71.1-2build1) ...
Setting up courier-authlib-mysql (0.71.1-2build1) ...
Setting up libcourier-unicode4:amd64 (2.1.2-2) ...
Setting up courier-authdaemon (0.71.1-2build1) ...
systemd-tmpfiles: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-245.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Could not execute systemctl:  at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke line 142.
Setting up courier-authlib-userdb (0.71.1-2build1) ...
Setting up courier-base (1.0.16-3build3) ...
Setting up courier-pop (1.0.16-3build3) ...
systemd-tmpfiles: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-245.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Could not execute systemctl:  at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke line 142.
Could not execute systemctl:  at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke line 142.
Setting up courier-imap (5.0.13+1.0.16-3build3) ...
systemd-tmpfiles: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-245.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Could not execute systemctl:  at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke line 142.
Could not execute systemctl:  at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke line 142.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...

>
● systemd-sysusers.service                                                                 loaded    failed failed    Create System Users                                           >
● systemd-timesyncd.service                                                                loaded    failed failed    Network Time Synchronization                                  >
● systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                                           loaded    failed failed    Cleanup of Temporary Directories                              >
● systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                                       loaded    failed failed    Create Static Device Nodes in /dev                            >
● systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                                           loaded    failed failed    Create Volatile Files and Directories
```

Does anyone knows how could I find all systemd inconsistencies and reinstall them? I'm worried about having lots of libraries linked to wrong systemd version.